# How could I make a Postgresql query for this case

Tags: postgresql

I have 03 tables with structure as below

1. Asset table: id, name
2. Device table: id, name
3. Relation table: from_id, to_id (these 2 columns link with either asset or device)

How could I make a query to get the result: from_id, from_name, to_id, to_name

Comment: What if an `asset` and a `device` have the same `id`?

Comment: Never be the same!

Answer (score 0):

You may join the asset/device table *twice* to the relation junction table.  For example, if you wanted to display for assets, you may try:

```
SELECT
    r.from_id,
    a1.name AS from_name,
    r.to_id,
    a2.name AS to_name
FROM Relation r
INNER JOIN Asset a1 ON r.from_id = a1.id
INNER JOIN Asset a2 ON r.to_id = a2.id;
```

Comment: You ma misunderstand my question. As you see, in the relation table, may be asset (from_id) contains asset (to_id) and/or asset(from_id) contain device (to_id). But I would like to make a query or function to list not only id (from_id, to_id) but also its name {asset name, device name)

Comment: No, you have misunderstood my answer.  My answer is giving you precisely what you asked for.

Comment: Not proper working with the case from_id (asset_id) and to_id(device_id). No row out!

Answer (score 0):

This data model doesn't look good to me. You can do this:

```
SELECT f.id AS from_id,
       f.name AS from_name,
       t.id AS to_id,
       t.name AS to_name
FROM (SELECT id, name FROM asset
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, name FROM device) AS f
   JOIN relation AS r ON r.from_id = f.id
   JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM asset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id, name FROM device) AS t
      ON r.to_id = t.id;
```

Alternatively, you can write the query as `UNION ALL` of four joins:

- `asset JOIN relation JOIN asset`
- `device JOIN relation JOIN asset`
- `asset JOIN relation JOIN device`
- `device JOIN relation JOIN device`

That will be a longer statement, but perhaps perform better.

Comment: @anhdv https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers